# PlatformIO CLion integration failed "Cannot run programm"

Tags: clion, platformio

Iam failing while integrating pio to the CLion IDE. I included the PATH variable to the ~/.profile file (three different ways) as:

`export PATH=$PATH:~/.platformio/penv/bin`

`export PATH=$PATH:home/jonas/.platformio/penv/bin`

`export PATH="~/.platformio/penv/bin":$PATH`

and can run the pio – version (and also the equivalent platformio) without sudo privelegies.

But when I’m trying to create a new pio project in CLion I always get
```Cannot run programm ./home/jonas/.platformio/penv/bin” (in directory “/tmp”): error=13, Permission denied``

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I got it working. The problem was that the path to pio was not complete. The path (/home/jonas/.platformio/penv/bin/home/jonas/.platformio/penv/bin) points to the folder but not to the file to run. The full path is:

`/home/jonas/.platformio/penv/bin/pio` (or platformio).

However, in the create project window, you don’t even get to correct the path and it was automatically created during installation. This is a bit confusing.